# Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I installed the @material-ui and its files are in node modules, but when I runng `npm run start` .

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui / core / grid.

```
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "react": "^17.0.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capitalize your import component name:

**Change**

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/grid';
```

**To**

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
```

**Or**

```
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
```